# How to unblock a nested div that has .block() applied

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I want to be able to "unblock" a div that has had .block() applied to it. How can I do this?

Here is some code to be more clear.

```
<div id='outer' style="width:300;height:300;background-color:black">
<div id= 'inner'>
    <a href=#>I want to be able to click this </a>
</div>

But nothing else in the "outer" div. <button> 
</div>

<script>
$('#outer').block();
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind providing an [example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @JoshCrozier example provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery BlockUI adds an overlay inside of the element when it is blocked. For example:

```
<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.6; cursor: wait; position: absolute; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
```

Therefore if you want one of the elements to be unblocked, you would need to increase the `z-index` of it so that it appears *above* the BlockUI overlay.

You could add a class to the element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/v1hfoa5L/)

```
.unblockable {
    z-index: 55555;
    position: relative;
}
```